# How can I get all records of taxonomy category in WordPress Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have use easy content Types plugin & created Post type in WP call Recipes. I have also added a taxonomy category in it & created 4 categories like Starter, Drinks, etc etc.

Now in WP query I need to get all records of starter.
So how can I get that?

I am using this query, but it is not working. It is giving all records of Recipes post type
Here is Query

```
$recipes = query_posts('post_type=recipes&taxonomy=recipescategory&category_name=Starters');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code and a misunderstanding about categories.

- Never use `query_posts` to construct a custom query

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination)

- If you have to run a custom query, make use of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
- `category_name` takes the category **slug**, **not the name**. The parameter's name is deceiving
- The "categories" belonging to a custom taxonomy are called terms. I have written a post which I have also included in the codex which you can check [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158223/31545), it describes the differences.
- To retrieve posts from a custom taxonomy, you need to make use of a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters). The category parameters will not work here

With all the above said, create your query so that it looks like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'recipescategory',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'Starters',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        //Your loop elements

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: No problem, I have left a comment on your other question, Try this code given on that problem. If you don't come right, leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

**try it**

```
 $ar = array (
       'post_type'=>'recipes',
       'taxonomy'=>'recipescategory',
       'category_name'=>'Starters'
    );     
    $posts = get_posts($ar);
```

** foreach loop**

```
 foreach($posts as $p){ ?>
             <div class="sub_cont">    
              <div class="sub_img"> 

                <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID));?>       
                <a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( $p->ID); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" longdesc="URL_2" alt="Text_2" /> </a>

            </div>
            <div class="desc_title">
               <a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( $p->ID); ?>">
                   <?php echo $post_title=$p->post_title; ?>
               </a>
           </div>
           <div class="cont_add"></div>          
        </div> 
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_posts function

```
$args = array("post_type"=>"recipes","category_name"=>"starter","posts_per_page"=>20);
$starters = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: Are you passing correct slug for post_type and category_name?  Try category instead of category_name.  You need to pass category ID.

Comment: i have done all those things guided by you & also use category instead of category_name but still it is not working